# How to end a loop if null returned?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, xpath, null

If I run through this loop on a specific page and the code is unable to find an xPath at the location determined within the loop I would like the loop to end. Here is the loop:

```
for i in range(1, maxListingsForLoops):            #@@@ADVERT NUMBER@@@
    if i > 10:
        break

    xPath = "/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[" +str(i)+ "]/div[1]/a[2]"
    getRenew = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
    getRenew = getRenew.get_attribute('href')
    #browser.get(getRenew)
    print(getRenew)
    time.sleep(speed)
```

When I run the loop line by line, I can see the variable is [], guessing that means it's empty which would make sense as on this page there is not a full page of listings so after five loops it will return nothing. 
I currently get this error :

```
$ xPath = "/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[7]/div[1]/a[2]"
$ print(xPath)
>>>>/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[7]/div[1]/a[2]
$ getRenew = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
$ print(getRenew)
>>>>[]
$ getRenew = getRenew.get_attribute('href')
>>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>>  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>>>>AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Does anyone know how to end the loop when the xPath variable returns zero, null or empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if not browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath):
    break
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't understand where this code should be added?
I tried before and after this line : 

    getRenew = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)

But both resulted in errors.

Comment: It depends on when you want to exit your loop - if you want to do so if `browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)` returns null/empty list, then add the if afterwards.

Comment: @C00P3RR I've edited my answer. Does it makes sense for you?

Comment: Yes it does help! But I got the error : invalid syntax pointing to the closing bracket around the xPath variable.

Comment: I don't think it's related. It is probably something with your `xPath` variable. Try to change it to: `xPath = f"/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[{i}]/div[1]/a[2]"`

Comment: Sadly not no, But also, if I delete the getRenew = then I'm no longer storing the path in a variable am I ?

Comment: True. But I don't think it will solve your problem. But I think you should consider asking it as a new question since your current issue is not related to the original question...